# Using Symfony CMF to feed Redis

Tags: symfony, redis, symfony-cmf

I'm supposed to make CMF feed a Redis queue which will then be polled by other servers. I'm still learning about CMF and it has become a little overwhelming to understand it. I've been using plain Symfony2 for a while, though.

I understand CMF can save the changes I made in the WYSIWYG editor as XML in the database. How much control do I have over this? Is there any project trying to interface CMF and Redis (or another non-doctrine database)?

I'm guessing I can implement a controller that would fetch these edited fragments from the database and send push them to Redis. But the fragments are in XML. Is there anything already built to fetch this data?

I appreciate any pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets briefly separate two things, the CMF is a set of components and Bundles that can largely be used independent of each other. All of them are storage agnostic but many currently only ship with support for PHPCR.

PHPCR in turn is a content repository interface for CMS which supports tree structures, full text search etc.

The reference implementation of that is called Jackalope. Jackalope in turn provides different so called "transports". You seem to be looking at the Doctrine DBAL transport for Jackalope which in deed stores XML fragments into an RDBMS. There is another one which uses the Jackrabbit Java server.

At any rate, writing a Redis based transport for Jackalope is probably not what you want. From what I can read is you actually just want a queue stored on Redis? In that case I would just use this Bundle here https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle together with standard Symfony2.

If you also want CMS editing capabilities, you can easily add CMF based editing into any Symfony2 project. Of course you would then use Redis for your queue and one of the Jackalope transport layers for storage. So you would be using more than one database. But this is a sensible architecture.

Comment: Note that the current dev version of the CMF CreateBundle just got support for Doctrine ORM too, in case you have simple content to edit. Either way, if you indeed want to use the CMF and copy some data to Redis, have a look at the Doctrine layer (phpcr-odm or orm, your choice) and event listeners there, to look at data in the object layer.

Comment: Thanks, you two. I'm checking out now CreatePHP and Create.js which seem to be the most relevant parts from CMF for content edition.